# Checking if an application is running using Windows Service

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-services, windows

I want to check if a particular application is running on my system using a windows service and if not I need to intimate the user about the same?
Please suggest a solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`Environment.UserInteractive` will be false for Windows Services and IIS processes (or generally: when no UI can be displayed).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ServiceController`

```
var controller = new ServiceController(processName);
```

and then investigate the controller.